# Node.js - module: nock - .reply with a callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

I'm using nock module to intercept HTTP calls to my API service (still undeveloped) and return some mock data that I have in a temporary database.

I notice the http requests are intercepted properly, but the problem that I see is that before my function gets required data from temp DB, the nock replies.

For a simple demonstration, look at the code below:

```
var nock = require('nock');

var nockReq = nock("http://localhost:8000")

    .post("/sample-endpoint")

    .reply(200, function (uri, requestBody) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            return {"result": "TIMED OUT"}
        }, 2000
    );
```

With the above code, when I don't use a time-out, I get the data returned properly as expected. But with this time-out, the nock doesn't seem to wait for the callback, instead proceed responding an empty 200 response.

Comment: This question is not about using callbacks on async functions. This problem is very specific to reply method in nock module.

Comment: It doesn't seems possible to do so with nock apparently

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684307/node-js-module-nock-reply-with-a-callback-doesnt-work

Comment: It is not possible at the moment, I have created this bug to handle that case: https://github.com/pgte/nock/issues/283

Answer (score -1):

You just put the function in setTimeOut to the next tick with nothing returned.
Try add return before setTimeOut.

Comment: Would you open an issue?